# How to find out the parent page Id from IPageStructure? (Composite C1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c1-cms

Is this the best way to get the parentId of a page from the IPageStructure in Composite C1 within a UserControl ?

```
string pPageId = SitemapNavigator.CurrentPageId.ToString();
Guid parentId = connection.Get<IPage>().Where(p => p.Id == new
   Guid(pPageId)).First().GetParentId();
```

I do use the present pageId as a string, which helps in the above case seeing as .First() can't be used on Guid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [SitemapNavigator](http://api.composite.net/html/T_Composite_Data_SitemapNavigator.htm) instance class you can grab from DataConnection - when you get the data bound instance it gives you access to the current page in form of a [PageNode](http://api.composite.net/html/AllMembers_T_Composite_Data_PageNode.htm) class from which you can access parent, child pages. You also have access to titles, descriptions etc.

```
// General (verbose) example - getting parent page ID
using (var connection = new DataConnection())
{
    var currentPageNode = connection.SitemapNavigator.CurrentPageNode;
    var parentPageNode = currentPageNode.ParentPage;
    var parentPageId = parentPageNode.Id;
}
```

If you are doing this from a Razor Function there is already a data connection available (this.Data) so the above can be written like this:

```
// Razor example - getting parent page ID    
var parentPageId = Data.SitemapNavigator.CurrentPageNode.ParentPage.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks mawtex, very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

One option is just to rely 100% on the standard asp.net way using the [SiteMapProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) functionality.

Get a specific node like this: `var node = SiteMap.CurrentProvider.FindSiteMapNodeByKey("...")`.
Get the Parent node like this: `var parentNode = node.ParentNode`.
Get its id like this: `var id = parentNode.Key`